# How to check input string format correctness, without reading the string?

Tags: matlab, input, error-handling

I am writing a script that takes two strings of the format 'HH:MM' as inputs.  These strings are times in hours (HH) and minutes (MM).  I would like to display an error message if the user inputs the wrong format for a time, such as 'HH:MM:SS' if they think the script can interpret seconds as well. I have it set up to accept negative times, so an input like '-HH:MM' will be interpreted correctly. An input like 'HHH:MMM' with variable hour and minute sizes is also OK, actually any input of the form %s:%s should be accepted since errors like '5:30 AM' are dealt with later.

What I need is to test that the inputs are of the form "string colon string" before reading, is this possible?  To make the problem clearer, here is code explaining how I read the inputs time1 and time2:

```
[hour1, min1] = strread(time1, '%s%s', 'delimiter', ':');
[hour2, min2] = strread(time2, '%s%s', 'delimiter', ':');
```

If time1 and time2 are formatted wrong, strread throws an unhelpful error.  I want to display my own error first to explain what the problem was.  How can I check the formats of time1 and time2 before actually reading them?

Ideas:

```
formatSpec = '%s : %s';
input = textscan(time1,formatSpec);
%Compare input to formatSpec somehow to see if they match?
if (no_match)
error('time1 must be formatted as HH:MM');
end
```

Comment: Can you `try` to read the input, `catch` the unhelpful error and inform the user of their mistake?

Comment: I did not know about `try` or `catch` that's a good idea.  Unfortunately just reading a wrong input doesn't always generate an error, just an empty cell in "input" for most cases, so this method is a little clunky to implement since I'd have to put a lot of code into the `try` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
time1 = '10:21';
if isempty(regexp(time1,'^\d{2}:\d{2}'))
    disp('the format is wrong') %won't display because the format if ok
end
```

And to check other format :

```
time1 = '100:21';
if isempty(regexp(time1,'^\d{2}:\d{2}'))
    disp('the format is wrong') %will display because the format is wrong
end
```

**EDIT**

If you want to accept 'HHH:MMM' and other cases use:

```
regexp(time1,'^\d+:\d+')
```

And for the negative case ('-HHH:MMM' or other negative cases) use:

```
regexp(time1,'^-\d+:\d+')
```

**Second edit**

And if you want to test it in only one line :

```
regexp(time1,'^(-|.){1}\d+:\d+$') % however this one doesn't support 'HH:MM AM'
regexp(time1,'^(-|.){1}\d+:\d+.+$') % Now support 'HH:MM AM'
```

I tested it and it returns `1` for every case you mentionned.

Comment: I like this answer best, there's just one problem, it can't detect a leading negative sign.  I think it's better if I only allow two input formats, 'HH:MM' for positive times or '-HH:MM' for negative times. Your first piece of code will restrict input to 'HH:MM', I would like to first check for an input '-HH:MM', how do I spot the negative sign?

Comment: @dynamo I made an Edit to my post, you can use `'^\d+:\d+'` instead of `\d{2}`. And for negative, just add the `-`.

Comment: I like the one line test, and my script doesn't support 'HH:MM AM' so its nice that this test exludes that immediately.  Just one error, the second parameter of regexp should read `^(-|){1}` instead of `^(-|.){1}` since '.' is the space char. I decided to go with `isempty(regexp(zone, '^(-|){1}\d{2}:\d{2}$'))`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you accept any numbers as long as there is only one `:` sign. In another words, perhaps you wanted to detect the more-than-one-colon case? You could count number of `:` signs and generate errors for those cases first before processing the string?

Comment: That would prevent users from entering seconds as well, but I think m_power's solution does a better job of dealing with all cases since it also handles inputs like '05:30 AM'